# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ while sending get request jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

when i insert get request through the url manually it works fine but when trying to pass it through jquery ajax im getting a return error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

it has to do with the way im passing param[SIGNATURE] but i dont know any other way to pass it ,  i cant use SIGNATURE:signature please dont recommend that it has to be how it is in url below

```
https://www.example.com/api/file.asp?userkey=USERKEY&action=ACTION&param[SIGNATURE]=SIGNATURE

 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: URL,
    crossDomain:true,
    data: {
              userkey: key,
              action: action,
              param[SIGNATURE]:signature},
    success: function(data){

console.log(data) ;
    }
  })
```

im trying to send this xml through jquery to the target

```
<REQUEST>
        <USERKEY>key</USERKEY>
    <ACTION NAME="action">
        <PARAMETER NAME="signature">signature</PARAMETER>
    </ACTION>
</REQUEST>
```

Comment: `param[SIGNATURE]` is an invalid property name. Use computed property names: `[param[SIGNATURE]]: signature` or `"param[SIGNATURE]": signature` if you mean the literal string `"param[SIGNATURE]"`.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: param is not defined when i try to use what you just said

Comment: Read my edited comment. I assumed, `param` was an existing object.

Comment: thanks mplungjan that works fine perfect

Comment: @xufox said the same :) `"param[SIGNATURE]": signature`

Comment: i just had to add the quotes , pretty cool appreciated